# How to write an if statement in ternary form?

Tags: lua

The commented code with the if statement does work correctly. However,
the ternary does not? Why is this or how can I implement this in
one simple line?

```lua
local function dontwork()
  local args = ""
  local cmd_tb = {}
  cmd_tb.args = ""

  -- dont work
  args = (#cmd_tb.args == 0 and false or cmd_tb.args)
  -- dont work
  -- args = (cmd_tb.args == "" and false or cmd_tb.args)

-- works correctly - empty
  -- if #cmd_tb.args == 0 then
  --   args = false
  -- else
  --   args = cmd_tb.args
  -- end

  if args then
    print("yes:",args)
  else
    print("empty")
  end
end

-- outputs 'yes'
dontwork()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common pitfall.

`cond and a or b` is *not* a ternary. It's just `(cond and a) or b`, which, due to lazy evaluation, behaves *almost* like a ternary:

- If `cond` is truthy, `cond and a` evaluates to `a`. If `a` is truthy, `a or b` then evaluates to `a`.
- If `cond` is falsey, `cond and a` evaluates to `cond`, so `cond or b` evaluates to `b`.

The problem is that if `a` is falsey (`nil` or `false`), then `a or b` evaluates to `b`, when it should evaluate to `a`.

In your case, since `b` is truthy (`nil` and `false` don't support `#`, unless you mess with debug metatables), you could just negate your condition and swap `a` and `b`:

```lua
args = #cmd_tb.args ~= 0 and cmd_tb.args or false
```

The `or false` is not necessary in this case, since `#cmd_tb.args ~= 0` will already evaluate to `false`. It may be necessary if your condition could be `nil`; `or nil` is also sometimes useful when you want `nil` rather than a boolean, but your condition produces a boolean.

PS: I would test for the empty string using `~= ""` / `== ""` respectively. It is clearer than comparing `#x` against `0`.

Comment: That makes sense, so in a nutshell you are saying that: -->#cmd_tb.args == 0 and false<-- produces `false` which then makes the statement: `args = false or cmd_tb.args` ? Which then gives something unexpected? Is there a reason you did not use (), I thought it was needed? What is this called z = (expr and x or y) need to look it up in my lua book.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. I used `(...)` once to be clear about precedence; it is not needed here. `expr and x or y` is sometimes called a "ternary", because if `x` is truthy it behaves like `expr ? x : y` in other languages, but it is not a "true" ternary because it doesn't work as expected if `x` is falsey. Maybe call it a "pseudo"-ternary? :-)

Answer (score 1):

```lua
args = (#cmd_tb.args == 0 and false or cmd_tb.args)
```

cannot work. Lua doesn't have a ternary statement. The `… and … or …` does not replace it completely. `(condition) and false` will always evaluate to `false` (or falsy `nil`, if `condition == nil`, per Luatic), and the "ternary statement" will always return the second alternative.

If you want a one-liner, you could rewrite this statement like this:

```lua
args = #cmd_tb.args > 0 and cmd_tb.args
```

Comment: Nitpick: `condition and false` may evaluate to `nil` instead of `false` if `condition` is `nil`.